# Capturing Function Pointer as Reference causes a segfault

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to understand why the following code causes a segfault:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;

    void callback1() {
        std::cout << "1 was called!" << std::endl;
    }

    void callback2() {
        std::cout << "2 was called!" << std::endl;
    }
};

std::function<void()> init(Foo& foo, void (Foo::*member_fn)()) {
    std::function<void()> func = [&foo, &member_fn]() {
                                    (foo.*member_fn)();
                                 };

    return func;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo foo;

    auto func = init(foo, &Foo::callback1);

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

Calling `func` works fine if I capture `member_fn` by value, but I don't see why it should matter.

Comment: `&member_fn` captures by reference but `member_fn` is local to the function

Comment: IMO, you should capture `member_fn` by value in the lambda to ensure its validity beyond the scope of `init`. By capturing by value, a copy of `member_fn` is stored within the lambda, preventing the dangling reference issue and avoiding the seg fault.

Comment: simpler example same effect https://godbolt.org/z/xT6sj88PM

Comment: This is basically "[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)". In this case, the local variable is the parameter `member_fn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the member function pointer by value, ie a copy is made, then capture that copy by reference. By the time you call the lambda the copy is gone and the referene is dangling.

Capture by value instead:

```
std::function<void()> init(Foo& foo, void (Foo::*member_fn)()) {
    std::function<void()> func = [&foo, member_fn]() { (foo.*member_fn)();};   
    return func;
}
```

---

There is no reason to use a reference in your code. Though, here is how you would pass a reference:

```
using memF = void(Foo::*)();

std::function<void()> init(Foo& foo, const memF& member_fn) {
    return [&foo, &member_fn]() { (foo.*member_fn)(); };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo foo;
    memF mf = &Foo::callback1;
    auto func = init(foo, mf);
    func();
    mf = &Foo::callback2;
    func();
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/335Tq6Txn):

```
1 was called!
2 was called!
```

Syntax is a little lighter if you employ the `std::mem_fn` wrapper utility: https://godbolt.org/z/j846G6d58.